# What does this regex achieve?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've seen this...

```
preg_match("/.*" . $row['keyword'] . ".*/", $word, $matches);
```

What does the pattern try to imply?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Note that any regex command characters in $row['keyword'] will be evaluated. If you just want to see if keyword is in a string, you can do `strpos($string, $row['keyword']) !== FALSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means find the term followed or preceded by 0 or more characters (`*`) which are not `\n` (`.`).

Unless it is done elsewhere, you ought to wrap `$row['keyword']` with `preg_quote($row['keyword'], '/')`.

Comment: It made sense. Does this `preg_quote` safe to use with German chars like umlaut?

Comment: @Defensor It should be, as it'll only look for chars that match a meta character which their codepoints are all less than `127`.

Comment: Thanks. If I will to modify this `preg_match` to match the exact word as from `$word` how will it be?

Comment: @Defensor Wrap the phrase with word boundaries (`\b`), e.g. `'/\b' . preg_quote($row['keyword'], '/') . '\b/'`.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation :**

```
/                            # start of the regex
.                            # match anything (any character, etc - except for /n)
*                            # zero or more times
" . $row['keyword']. "       # match the keyword
.*                           # same as above
/                            # end of the regex
```

Answer (score 1):

`/` is just the pattern delimiter, and `.*` means "any character (other than newline) repeated 0 or more times," so it's simply searching for occurrences of whatever string is in `$row['keyword']`, in `$word`.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to find out whether `$row['keyword']` is contained within `$word`, it's also safer  to call `preg_quote` to `$row['keyword']` in case the keyword contains meta characters such as `*`, `/`, `\` etc